# Trying to Implement a Split Predicate in Prolog

Tags: list, split, prolog, predicate

I am trying to implement a `partition` predicate in Prolog that splits a list into its two halves, a Prefix and a Suffix, of approximately same lengths.

```
partition(L,P,S)
```

Where prefixes and suffixes are defined as such:

```
prefix(P,L) :- append(P,_,L).
suffix(S,L) :- append(_,S,L).
```

- If `L` is `[]`, then `Prefix` and `S` are `[]`.
- If `L` is `[H]`, then `P` is `[H]` and `S` is `[]`.
- If `L` has two or more elements, this is how the list is partitioned into its prefix and suffix:

  - Length of `L` is `N` and the length of `P` is `div(N,2)`. The length of `S` is `N - div(N,2)`.

So for instance:

```
?- partition([a,b,c,d],X,Y).

X = [a,b]
Y = [c,d]

?- partition([a],X,Y).

X = [a]
Y = [ ]
```

Here is my code and the error I get:

```
partition([],[],[]).
partition([H],[H],[]). 
partition(L, P, S) :-
    length(L, N),
    Plen is div(N,2),
    Slen is N - div(N,2),
    length(Pre, Plen),
    length(Suff, Slen),
    prefix(Pre, L),
    suffix(Suff, L),
    P is Pre,
    S is Suff.

partition([a,b,c,d],X,Y).

>>> Type error: `[]' expected, found `[a,b]' (a list) 
    ("x" must hold one character)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this error message but this is wrong:

```
    P is Pre,
    S is Suff.
```

This is for arithmetic evaluation whereby the Right-Hand-Side is evaluated as an arithmetic expression and unified with the Left-Hand-Side.

You just want to unify the variables:

```
    P = Pre,
    S = Suff.
```

Alternatively, you can use the same same for `P` and `Pre` / `S` and `Suff` throughout.

Comment: The error message come from the arithmetic evaluation of (single) characters (I think). Try `?- X is "2".` vs `?- X is "23".`. Would be nice to know what ISO standard has to say about.

Comment: @CapelliC `?- X is "2", integer(X).` ...  `X = 50.`. SWI-Prolog is going a bit too far I think. Although `X is [a], integer(X).` with `X=97` is sort of expected as there is no difference between characters and their unicode codepoints. Although if there is a list I would expect a vector operation to be used instead. That would actually make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `is` to to `=` as suggested by David Tonhofer's answer, the whole thing works.

But I would like to add that you are complicating things a bit. You have identified correctly that `append/3` can be used to compute list prefixes and suffixes. But for any list to be partitioned and any prefix, the suffix is unique, and is already computed by `append/3`! And the other way round: If you ask it to compute a suffix, it will also compute the prefix you seek. But then you throw these answers away and try to recompute a matching prefix or suffix. There is no need to do that.

If we make your prefix and suffix predicates a bit more explicit:

```
list_prefix_theonlypossiblematchingsuffix(List, Prefix, TheOnlyPossibleMatchingSuffix) :-
    append(Prefix, TheOnlyPossibleMatchingSuffix, List).

list_suffix_theonlypossiblematchingprefix(List, Suffix, TheOnlyPossibleMatchingPrefix) :-
    append(TheOnlyPossibleMatchingPrefix, Suffix, List).
```

We can see that once we have a given prefix for a list, there really is no more choice for the suffix (and vice versa):

```
?- list_prefix_theonlypossiblematchingsuffix([a, b, c, d], Prefix, MatchingSuffix).
Prefix = [],
MatchingSuffix = [a, b, c, d] ;
Prefix = [a],
MatchingSuffix = [b, c, d] ;
Prefix = [a, b],
MatchingSuffix = [c, d] ;
Prefix = [a, b, c],
MatchingSuffix = [d] ;
Prefix = [a, b, c, d],
MatchingSuffix = [] ;
false.
```

So there is no need to try to compute the prefix and suffix separately and to match up their lengths. It's enough to restrict the prefix, as the suffix will follow:

```
partition(List, Prefix, TheOnlyPossibleMatchingSuffix) :-
    length(List, N),
    PrefixLength is N div 2,
    length(Prefix, PrefixLength),
    list_prefix_theonlypossiblematchingsuffix(List, Prefix, TheOnlyPossibleMatchingSuffix).
```

This works as you want:

```
?- partition([a, b, c, d], Prefix, Suffix).
Prefix = [a, b],
Suffix = [c, d].

?- partition([a, b, c, d, e], Prefix, Suffix).
Prefix = [a, b],
Suffix = [c, d, e].
```

Once you have this, it's much clearer to replace the goal involving `list_prefix_verylongpredicatename` with what is really meant:

```
partition(List, Prefix, Suffix) :-
    length(List, N),
    PrefixLength is N div 2,
    length(Prefix, PrefixLength),
    append(Prefix, Suffix, List).
```

Coming from other programming languages it may be a bit unusual that a predicate like `append/3` computes several things at once that have a deep relationship with each other, i.e., a prefix *and* the unique matching suffix. But this is one of the things that makes Prolog so expressive and powerful. Get used to it and profit from it!

Comment: your last code is still too *imperative*. :) you end with `append`; I've posted an answer that starts with it! (so then `partition( L, [1,2], [3] ).` works, instead of looping). FYI.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're doing a lot of unnecessary work here.

This is all I think you need:

```
partition(L,P,S) :-
    partition(L,L,P,S).

partition(L,[],[],L).
partition(([H|L],[_],[H],L).
partition([H|L],[_,_|L2],[H|P],S) :-
    partition(L,L2,P,S).
```

If I query `?- partition([a],X,Y), write([X,Y]).` then I get:

```
[[a], []]
true.
```

If I query `?- partition([a,b,c,d,e],X,Y), write([X,Y]).` then I get:

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e]]
true.
```

Comment: since you're counting already, why not count in unary, and by two at once as well? (hint: *tortoise and hare algorithm*) that way you'll get the minimal definition which won't be retracing the list needlessly. :) it will even become multi-directional, a true relation. (I think). right now your definition has fused the append and the second length from IsabelleNewbie's code, but that way you'd fuse even the first length into your code.

Comment: also, by the 2nd rule in the question, they actually want the first half to be no shorter than the second. the `div(N,2)` in the OP's third rule is an error, it should be `ceil(N / 2)`.

Comment: @WillNess - Yes, much nicer with the Tortoise and the Hare.

Comment: @WillNess - I changed the 2nd `partition/4` - so it now works with a single item list, but it does seem that the OP's rule is flawed.

Comment: now it's *perfect*. :) (except for the name, of course). and it does work in all directions: `partition( L, [a,b,c], [d,e]).` works!

Comment: I ended up posting an answer as well. it is also omnidirectional. the code is mush simpler, at the cost of doing a bit more work than necessary, behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already defined your prefixes and suffixes as

```erlang
prefix(P,L) :- append(P, _, L).         % prefix
suffix(S,L) :- append(_, S, L).         % suffix
```

just smash the two together into one call,

```erlang
partition(L,P,S) :- 
               append(P, S, L),
```

and this would be *it*, except you have additional conditions about the comparative lengths of the two near-halves, so just add them into the mix:

```erlang
    length( P, N), length( A, N),      % same length, fresh list A
    (A = [_|S] ; A = S).               % S one shorter than P, or same length
```

And that's that. Testing:

> ```erlang
> 2 ?- partition( [1,2,3], A, B ).
> A = [1, 2],
> B = [3].
>
> 3 ?- partition( L, [1,2], [3] ).
> L = [1, 2, 3].
>
> 15 ?- partition( L, A, B ).
> L = A, A = B, B = [] ;
> L = A, A = [_G2477],
> B = [] ;
> L = [_G2477, _G2483],
> A = [_G2477],
> B = [_G2483] ;
> L = [_G2477, _G2483, _G2492],
> A = [_G2477, _G2483],
> B = [_G2492] ;
> L = [_G2477, _G2483, _G2489, _G2492],
> A = [_G2477, _G2483],
> B = [_G2489, _G2492]
> ....
> ```